# Writing web service response to excel

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I am trying to wrote the response of a restful service response to excel.

In the below once, if my test case response is below one, then i need to write to csv or excel for sheet1 (in excel) TC01, sampleResponse

```
<user-batch-result xmlns="http://www.xxxxxx.com/api//02" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<records-succeeded>1</records-succeeded>
<records-failed>0</records-failed>
<UsersDetails>
    <UserInfo>
        <EmployeeID>xxxxx</EmployeeID>
        <FeedRecordNumber>0</FeedRecordNumber>
        <Status>SUCCESS</Status>
    </UserInfo>
</UsersDetails>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

1. Download [tika-app.jar](https://tika.apache.org/download.html) and drop it somewhere to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) (i.e. to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation). JMeter restart will be required to pick the .jar up.
2. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the above response
3. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def wb = new org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook()
   def sheet1 = wb.createSheet("sheet1")
   def row = sheet1.createRow(0)
   def A1 = row.createCell(0, org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType.STRING)
   A1.setCellValue(prev.getResponseDataAsString())

   wb.write(new File('myFile.xlsx'))
   ```
4. Run your test.
5. If everything goes well you should see `myFile.xlsx` having `Sheet1` and the response of your Web Service as the very first cell value. Feel free to amend this code as required according to your use case.

References:

- [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NewWorkbook)
- [How to Implement Data Driven Testing in your JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-implement-data-driven-testing-in-your-jmeter-test)